# Monthly % change power bi

Tags: powerbi, dax

Hoping someone can help! Each month I receive a finance file, the total number of rows varies each month. The two columns of interest are financial_ref (which is a unique identifier for each month, though repeated across months) and outcome (which is either yes or no). A 100% stacked bar chart can show the yes/no% each month (axis = date, value = count(financial_ref), legend = outcome), but what I'd also like is a chart which can show the % difference each month. So if 'No' was 48% in March and 50% in April, I'd like a chart which shows +2% for 'no' for April, being the increase from the previous month (and likewise shows -2% for 'yes' for April). There's an additional column 'category' which stakeholders would use to filter any visualisations built. No idea where to start...

[image]

Comment: Please provide the data table with relevant columns including some data and the result you oulw like to soo so we can help you.

Comment: Hi @Aldert, I've testing on a small sample table, as above. If a solution could work for the test table, it would work for my main table too (apologies, didn't know how to insert a table rather than an image)